# (mac-bootcamp) WiFi not connecting when ethernet adapter (with no cable) is plugged in

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, boot-camp

I'm on a 2016 usbC MBP running W10, the issue arises when i plug in a multiport adapter (C -> A + HDMI + ethernet), which i use for USB and HDMI, but not Ethernet, as I am connected to WiFi.

When i plug the adapter in, the wireless connection abruptly stops working.

When I try to reconnect to it, Windows gives me a "can't connect to network" message, and browsers currently loading pages crash (both chrome and edge).

I tried disabling, uninstalling, reinstalling both drivers and the device itself, as well as resetting my router, and the usual flushDNS.

When I plug in the adapter, wifi stays connected, albeit with no internet connection.
In this state IPConfig gives me my ISP details in my wireless connection, all other connections report as disabled.

When I disconnect and try reconnecting to the network, i get the above Windows error.

All drivers are up to date, in fact one of the few times that I got it working was when I updated the wireless drivers from Apple.

Today it stopped working again.

Here's the Windows error reporting

https://pastebin.com/QQUm2rWf